# Using permutations with probability

Tags: probability

> A bag contains four red, three green and five yellow marbles. Three marbles are drawn, one at a time, without replacement. Determine the probability that the order in which they are selected is:
>
> yellow, red, green

$$P(YRG) = \frac{3!}{\frac{12!}{(12-3)!}} = \frac{3!}{1320} = \frac{6}{1320} = \frac{1}{220}$$

The correct answer is 1/22, so somewhere I messed up, can anyone help me?

## I'm not familiar with how to properly write fractions on this website.

Comment: To write a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ type \frac{a}{b}

Comment: Thank you, editing post now! :)

Comment: hint:  what is the probability that the first marble is yellow? Given that you have removed a yellow, what's the probability that the second one chosen is red? And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Look at the probability of "winning" at each step along the way.  Assume that you "won" the previous step (meaning that you drew what you needed).

For the first step, you need to draw a yellow marble.  There are $5$ yellow marbles, and $12$ marbles total.  The probability that you win this step is therefore $P_1 = \frac{5}{12}.$

Afterwards, you only have $11$ marbles in the bag.  How many of each color do you have?  What, then, is the probably of winning step 2?

Let's call that probability $P_2$, which is the probability of drawing a red, *given that* you drew a yellow at step 1.  Then, the probability of winning both step 1 and step 2 is $P_1 \cdot P_2$.

Finally, calculate the probability of winning step 3, *given that* you've taken out one yellow and one red.  Call this $P_3$.

Now, the probability of winning the entire thing -- yellow first, red second, green third -- is $P_1 \cdot P_2 \cdot P_3$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand, however I'm not sure if I should write it out like I have above, or if my way would not work, rather than writing out all the fractions?

 
Would it be redundant to write out: 5/12 + 4/11 + 3/10 and so on?

Comment: Both what you wrote in your question, and in the comment above, aren't correct.  I've edited my answer to lead through a bit more.  But your comment is closer.  You just have to multiply those numbers instead of add them.